# Run Time and Compatibility Errors using Variable Type "Double"

Tags: vba, excel, double, regional-settings

I have a strange issue using `Double` type variables in my VBA Macros.

**The Macro works fine when I test it on some systems, but causes a runtime error '1004' when tested on another system with different language settings.
Both systems use Office 2013.**

I have a ScrollBar in a form, with values ranging from -50 to + 50. 
Basically an indicator to increase/decrease the value of a range by -/+ 50% 
The Macro is something simple like follows:

---

```
Dim multiplier As Double

multiplier = CLng(Me.DPScroll.Value) / 100 + 1
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("AB11:AB" & LR).Formula = "=H11*" & multiplier
```

---

When the `DPScroll.Value = 0` (Multiplier = 1), the form runs file without any errors, but if it has a positive or negative value, it returns

> Run-time Error 1004 : Application Defined/Object Defined Error

(On my system, both work fine)

So, I'm guessing the Multiplier is unable to take values in Decimal Points (Eg. 1.07 to increase by 7%)

(Less important issue)
It also causes a strange formatting error on another sheet. 
I'm calculating the average of a few rows in a list box and pasting the value to a range. On some systems, the format is retained, but on others it changes and gets multiplied by millions and a Large number is displayed (like 10^E6 times)

Since this is restricted to some systems - are there any regional/language compatablity issues with suing "Double" variable type.

Comment: You cast multiplier to Long (CLng), you have to cast it into a double (CDbl)

Comment: @flohdieter But casting to Long should still not give an error.

Comment: What line is the error actually occurring on? Nothing appears obviously wrong in the above code which suggests the error is actually being caused elsewhere. If it's inconsistent then it's quite likely to be an issue with using `ActiveSheet` or similar

Comment: As long as you use `.Formula` the regional settings are always standard US that means the multiplier has to be `1.07` (e.g. not `1,07`). But if you use `.FormulaLocal` then the decimal point depends on the local settings of windows.

Comment: ^^ and the implicit cast to string in `"=H11*" & multiplier` will be done using local settings

Comment: Hey guys - the (CLng) is to cast the value in the scrollbar to number - it is not a decimal value, I only need to convert it later when i Divide by 100... The issue seems to be with localization as Peh Suggeted below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed a localization issue. As long as you use `.Formula` the regional settings are always standard US that means the multiplier has to be `1.07` (e.g. not `1,07`).

But if the localization is German for example then if the multiplier is cast to a string it becomes `1,07` but `.Formula` needs the US standard `1.07`.

---

**Solution 1**
Replace any comma `,` in `multiplier` to `.` using `replace()`

---

**Solution 2**
use `.FormulaLocal` to use the localized formula:

```
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("AB11:AB" & LR).FormulaLocal= "=H11*" & multiplier
```

But then you probably have to deal with other issues like e.g. `=IF(A1=0,TRUE,FALSE)` becomes localized too (e.g. for german): `=WENN(A1=0;WAHR;FALSCH)`.

---

**Solution 3**
Another approach would be to write the multiplier into a named range, so you can use that name in your formula directly as following:

```
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("AB11:AB" & LR).Formula = "=H11*multiplier"
```

Therefore you can use `ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add "multiplier", multiplier` so you even don't need a helper cell for that named range.

But then if you change the multiplier any time, it also changes for every old formula in your sheets where the named range `multiplier` was used.

Comment: Added a third solution. Every solution has its advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Thanks a million Peh - yes i Figured it was a Localization issue, esp with european teams, so it could be that they use comma "," instead or decimal "."... I'll try out the solutions here and do some further testing and see if it works :)